# using lambda in pd.apply() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column 'categories'. That column has list as elements and each list contains some words. I want to find in how many lists the words "pizza" or "Italian" appear. The columns look like:
 [image: screenshot how the columns look like]

I tried the code below, but I am getting everything as `False`.

```
business.categories.apply(lambda x: ('pizza' in x) or ("Italian" in x))
```

Comment: Please post the sample of your dataframe as text in the question, not as a picture. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Try `business.categories.apply(lambda x: {'italian', 'pizza'} < x)`

Comment: I am not able to re-create this behavior locally creating my own example from your screenshot.  As @G.Anderson if you post a sample of the dataframe into the question the community will be able to provide further help

Comment: Lists in dataframes isn't really a good use case for pandas

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `or` use `|`

`business['categories'].map(lambda x: ('pizza' in x) | ("Italian" in x))`

pandas doesn't like `and` or `or`, use `&` or `|`

Something to note:

Make sure the values in your list don't have whitespaces, for example `Italian` and `_Italian` are different. If that's the case you have to do this in two pars

Cleaning

`business['categories'] = business['categories'].map(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x])`

then map

`business['categories'].map(lambda x: ('pizza' in x) | ("Italian" in x))`

Comment: still getting all as False

Comment: please post the head of the dataframe so I can test

Comment: but they do have white spaces now what to do ?

Comment: then of course you get all false, you have to remove that first before checking

Comment: is there any way to remove all those white spaces

Comment: Use .strip() to remove whitespaces if i understand correctly
business['categories'].map(lambda x: ('pizza' in x.strip()) | ("Italian" in x.strip()))

Comment: updated to account for white spaces, @No_body, your approach won't work because `x` is a `list` in `lambda` not `str`